# Getting contents of complex NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am calling an API which returns some high level data in `JSON` format. This is then being processed into an `NSDictionary` like so;

```
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

When I log this I can a very complicated result similar to this:

```
{
 one = {
         oneone = 12345;
         onetwo = "Hello";
         onethree = "How Are You";
       };
 two = 42;
 three = {
           threeone = {
                        threeoneone = "Name";
                        threeonetwo = {
                                          threeonetwoone = "100";
                                          threeonetwotwo = "26";
                                       };
etc etc etc
```

Now I get the contents of 'three' by calling `[results objectForKey:@"three"]` but how do I get the value of 'threeonetwoone'?

I have tried a few things but to no avail.

Comment: That indentation it a little confusing, also, one, two, three, etc... should be in quotes.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri : your problem solved by formatting :)

Comment: I did a lot of stuffs to order the code, posted first, second answer came after five minutes... but no no results ;(

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri -- That's a dump of the dictionary -- NSLog doesn't print quotes around the keys unless they contain odd characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case:

```
NSString* threeoneone= dict[@"three"][@"threeone"][@"threeonetoone"];
```

Comment: Excellent! This is great. My Dictionary is very complex so (for example) if "threeone" appears several times, then I use `dict[@"three"][@"threeone"][i][@"threeonetwo"]` where i is the index. Cheers

Comment: In this case you would have an array inside the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this... please check it in compiler

As I am not sure, you have mentioned correct dictionary or not, and all your keys should be correct.

```
[results valueForKeyPath:@"three.threeone.threeonetwo.threeonetwoone"];
```

Comment: There is no `objectForKeyPath` method.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks for nice catch, i updated the answer. as you read I did not check my answer in compiler so that silly mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

With the recent changes in Objective-C syntax you can do it like that:

```
results[@"three"][@"threeone"][@"threeonetwo"][@"threeonetwoone"];
```

Comment: Yep, great answer but noticed Ramy's was first. Cheers though.

Comment: @Patrick No. I was first ;( I posted this 3 minutes before him.

Comment: @Patrick: If this is the case see i am 3 min earlier than nikola and 6 min earlier than Ramy :p

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yes. That is correct, but I guess he likes this syntax.

Comment: @NikolaKirev: haha. Whats to like in this new syntax. even I can write  and copy paste now :p Even i see his answer is wrong... just compare with mine and yours answer and the dictionary stucture.

Comment: Sorry @AnoopVaidya your answer didn't work in my scenario as there are arrays in my dictionary. I reward with +1 though.

Comment: @Patrick:  I can not see any array in your dictionary, posted in the question. I replied according to the question ? :(